# Generic class, understand of generic params

Tags: java, generics

I am having some trouble understanding why eclipse complains.
I have two interfaces:

```
@Preload
public interface KBaseAo extends FAQ
{
    public static final String ID = "BASE_KEY";
}

public interface FAQ extends Entity {
    @Unique
    @NotNull
    String getBaseKey();
    void setBaseKey(String baseKey);

    @NotNull
    String getExcerpt();
    void setExcerpt(String excerpt);
}
```

where the Entity interface:

```
public interface Entity extends RawEntity<Integer> {
    @AutoIncrement
    @NotNull
    @PrimaryKey("ID")
    public int getID();
 }
```

The concrete class looks like this:

```
public class FAQServiceImpl<T extends FAQ> {    
    private void save(Class<T> clazz, String ID_FIELD, String key, String excerpt) {
        T entity = (T) aoManager.create(clazz, new DBParam(ID_FIELD, key),
                new DBParam("EXCERPT", excerpt));
        entity.save();
    }

    private <T extends FAQ> void save2(Class<T> clazz, String ID_FIELD, String key, String excerpt) {
        T entity = (T) aoManager.create(clazz, new DBParam(ID_FIELD, key),new DBParam("EXCERPT", excerpt));
            entity.save();
   }
    public Map<String, String> fetchExcerptsFor(Set<String> bodies) {
         //call save2 or save here
    }
}
```

I am trying to call the save as

```
save(KBaseAo.class, "SomeID", "SomeStr", "SomeStr");
```

which gives compilation error

```
The method save(Class<T>, String, String, String) in the type FAQServiceImpl<T> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<KBaseAo>, String, String, String)
```

Calling the save2 exactly the same

```
save2(KBaseAo.class, "SomeID", "SomeStr", "SomeStr");
```

compiles perfectly but overwrites the T type.

What am I missing and can't make the save() to work?

Edit:
Added calling code of the two saves

Comment: Where are you invoking `save` (or `save2`) with 4 parameters? It looks like you are doing it in an instance method of `FAQServiceImpl<T>`, so `T` is not necessarily `KBaseAo`.

Comment: How is the object on which you are invoking those methods declared?

Answer (score 2):

Your `save` method makes use of the class-level type variable `T`. In doing this, you are asking the compiler to ensure that this method is invoked only with a class instance whose type exactly matches the generic type of the instance.

For example:

```
FAQServiceImpl<FooFAQ> instance = new FAQServiceImpl<>();
instance.save(FooFAQ.class, "", "", "", "");  // Fine.
```

You can't invoke this with some arbitrary class which also happens to implement `FAQ`, because it doesn't match the type of `instance`:

```
FAQServiceImpl<FooFAQ> instance = new FAQServiceImpl<>();
instance.save(BarFAQ.class, "", "", "", "");  // Compiler error.
```

But this is what you are doing in your code currently: you are saying that `FAQServiceImpl` has a generic type `T`, but you want to invoke the method with a specific type `KBaseAo`:

```
FAQServiceImpl<T> instance = new FAQServiceImpl<>();
instance.save(KBaseAo.class, "", "", "", "");  // Compiler error.
```

(even though this goes on inside instance methods in the class).

However, `save2` defines a new type variable, which *just happens* to have the same name `T`. There is no relationship between this new type variable and the class-level variable `T`.

As such, the declaration of `save2` doesn't require the classes to match: it just needs *some* class which implements `FAQ`.

Comment: I get why (my) second save is working and the first not. What is still unclear to me is why i have to call instance.save(FooFAQ.class.....) since the instance is already instantiated with FooFAQ. My ultimate goal was to avoid passing class references from once object to another

Answer (score 0):

There is a critical difference between this method ...

```
public void save(Class<T> clazz, String ID_FIELD, String key, String excerpt)
```

... and this one ...

```
public <T extends FAQ> void save2(Class<T> clazz, String ID_FIELD, String key, String excerpt)
```

.  The former is a normal method of a generic *class*, whereas the latter is a generic *method*, which could belong to either a generic class or an ordinary one.  In particular, the `T` in the second method is the one declared as `<T extends FAQ>` in the method signature, and it has nothing to do with any type parameter `T` that may be declared by the host class.

Thus the `T` in the first method is the explicit or inferred `T` from the declaration of the **object** on which the method is invoked, whereas the `T` in the second method is the explicit or inferred one from the invocation of the method.  Nothing requires there to be any relationship between these, and it would therefore be clearer to use a different type parameter in the latter (which would also have the result of not shadowing the class's type parameter of the same name).

Furthermore, you need to be aware that regardless of any relationship between two types `T` and `U`, the types `Klass<T>` and `Klass<U>` are not assignment-compatible in either direction.  This is why, for instance, you cannot assign a `List<String>` to a variable of type `List<Object>`.

If you invoke one of your methods from one of the class's other methods, then the compiler doesn't know what value the class's type parameter `T` has.  The specific `save()` invocation you present is valid only when `T` is `KBaseAo`, but nothing the compiler sees guarantees that `T` will have that value.  The invocation of `save2()`, on the other hand, doesn't care what value the class's type parameter has.  The value of that method's own type parameter of the same name can be inferred from the method arguments -- specifically, from the first one.